# Module not found error in Jenkins while trying to run wdio from docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, package.json, wdio-v5

I am using webdriverio . My package.json is having all my dependency. I have created a docker image for my project throught Jenkins using a docker file. Now I am trying run the scripts from Jenkins. It is failing saying module not found. For example in config file I have used var json=require('cjson') . Same has been installed in docker image . But when  I run through Jenkins it fails saying module cjson not found

Answer (score 0):

Build container on your local and try to run it from there and check:

**1. Is your dependency installation script running?

2. See if there are any error for specific module that's failing**

Best